# Edited libappmenu.so and now apps only run as root

Tags: segmentation-fault

so I was trying to add global menu support for Eclipse from this short fix from [here](http://elvisd.blogspot.ca/2012/01/enable-eclipse-global-menu-integration.html) and it worked. I tried adding another application into that by typing the application in there as well and it didn't work, so I removed it.

Since then, I can't run a lot of applications after a restart. They all say Segmentation fault (core dump).

Here is a core dump file from one application Synergy: https://gist.github.com/2974295

This only seems to be happening to my user account though. Other accounts and root can start up fine..

I would really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try re-installing the `appmenu-gtk` package:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall appmenu-gtk
```

I hope this works.

Comment: Worked great! I didn't know the package it belonged to before. :)

Comment: You can find out which package a file belongs to using `dpkg -S /path/to/file`. If the file isn't installed (e.g. you know you need a certain development header file or a library), you can install the utility [`apt-file`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt-file).